# Why is Exception Value: cursor "_django_curs_140539182187712_sync_1" error generated in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

I am getting the below error on Herokuapp site, while the local version of my Django app works just fine.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

**Note:**

1. The site was not being recognized earlier, and had to add SITE_ID=1 to my `settings.py` file)
2. I have deleted all migrations and SQL DB and refreshed everything from start.

`Exception Value:column home_article.Influencers1_id does not exist`

````
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://www.manishrathee.com/Article
Django Version:     3.1.13
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

column home_article.Influencers1_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ome_article"."tag2_id", "home_article"."tag3_id", "home_arti...
                                                             ^

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:     3.9.6
Python Path:    

['/app/rathee',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf',```

The error can be viewed here – http://www.manishrathee.com/Article.

** ADDED ** 

I also receive this error in the Admin area –
````

Error during template rendering

In template /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
cursor "_django_curs_140244460422336_sync_1" does not exist
9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
{% if field.is_checkbox %}
{{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
{% else %}
{{ field.label_tag }}
{% if field.is_readonly %}
{{ field.contents }}
{% else %}
{{ field.field }}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if field.field.help_text %}
{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

```
Many thanks!
```

Comment: You deleted all your migrations? Did you recreate them and then run migrate?

Comment: Yes, if you visit www.manishrathee.com, you would see the site working but if you go to `Quote Cards` or `Articles` you see the error there...

Comment: Are those models in the same app and are they the only models in that app? Sounds like you are missing some migrations

Comment: I have two apps in the project, I have done – 1. Deleted the Database 2. Deleted the **migrations** 3. Run makemigration, migrate & createsuperuser.

Comment: Do you have migration files in the "home" app? If you delete the migrations directory of an app you need to run `python manage.py makemigrations <app>` to create an initial migration file and directory, otherwise `makemigrations` will just skip the app

Comment: The only ones I have under home & Tweet are `__init__.py` and now that it is up, it has `0001_initial.py`, nothing else. The whole saga started with us getting site doesn't exist and had to add `SITE_ID=1` to `Settings.py`.... :(

Comment: Can you add the article model to your question? And maybe the section of your migration that adds this model would help, something is definitely wrong with your migrations

Comment: Can it be shared privately since it is Client Confidential? if you sign or if you are on twitter, I could create an admin for you. I am @SystemsHq there

Comment: I have 'chat warnings' here... so will leave it at that.

Comment: I have a twitter account, pretty bare though, feel free to message me. If makemigrations isn't saying you don't have any changes and migrate doesn't do anything it might be worth dropping the DB again but not your migrations, not sure how your deployment process goes but it may have some issues that cause it to either use old migrations or fail at some point

Answer (score 0):

Heroku git repositories are separate & distinct from Git Hub. You would need to delete your Heroku App and reestablish it for it to work again.